# launchd doesn't launch my daemon

Tags: macos, launchd, daemons

I'm trying to figuring out why my daemon doesn't be launched automatically (on Mac 10.8.3). However, it works well on other machines. Here is my plist under /Library/LaunchDaemons/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"   "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.MyApp.tmsm.launcher</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/Application Support/MyApp/tmsmLauncher</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

I didn't see any error messages in `/var/log/system.log`. I have checked the `permission` and `owner` of my `daemon`. If i put my plist under `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/`, it can be launched after `reboot`. But it's not a good solution for me. If i use "`launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.MyApp.tmsm.launcher`", it works well. If i install other commercial software which is a daemon and have a plist under `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`, it can't be launched, too.

It seems any plist under `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` isn't loaded by system. I also try to turn on launchctl debug level with the command, "`launchctl log level debug`", but there is no more messages after reboot. Is the debug level reset after reboot? Is other logs or configs i can check??

Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at the job definition file. launchd(8) will refuse to load job if:

 - the job definition file is writable by `group` or `other`
 - the job definition is not owned by `root` (or the user specified in the job definition)
 - the job definition file name does not end with `.plist`

Comment: the permission and owner of the definition file is correct. `-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the root cause...It's quite stupid...
The permission of my plist under /Library/LaunchDaemons/ is correct. However, the permission of /Library/LaunchDaemons/ is modified to 755. That's why any daemons registered under /Library/LaunchDaemons/ can't be loaded automatically...

Comment: /Library/LaunchDaemons permissions on my system are 755 and it works fine. I haven't changed it myself so I assume its the default.

Comment: On 10.11, they *appear* to be 644 by default.

Comment: Directories must have the `x` bit so 644 makes no sense

Answer (score 4):

Try to load it with -w parameter: `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/blablabla.plist`. Looks like problem in Disabled key. see `man launchctl` for details.

If that will not work I suggest you to enable some logging to file in your daemon to see if it starts (may be it just exits immediately?)

Comment: Load my daemon with/without -w parameter manually is fine. My daemon can't be loaded automatically while system starts. My daemon does have logs at the beginning and it doesn't show. I also used `launchctl list` to check my daemon has been loaded or not and i couldn't see my daemon on the list.
I checked the Disabled key in `/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist` but i can't see my daemon on this plist.

Comment: Before your daemon will start automatically at system start, you need to load it first with -w parameter.